# HTML5 canvas display image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

i would like to command my image.

Basically i have this code already;
But how to i move my image to its desired location?
Like a little bit on left, more to right, i mean the coordinates... where should i put it here?

```
  if(document.getElementById('fig1').checked){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fsFMyfNLNG8/TuZs45U0dZI/AAAAAAAAg38/QIjqug0MnAo/Ic42/barbie6.png';

      }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drawImage()` method of canvas has two coordinates (`x` and `y`). If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), you'll see, the second and third parameters of `drawImage()` method represents the `x-coordinates` and `y-coordinates` of the image respectively. So, you can move around the image to its desired location by changing those coordinates.

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10)
                             ^   ^
```

**DEMO**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var context2 = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch_2').getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fsFMyfNLNG8/TuZs45U0dZI/AAAAAAAAg38/QIjqug0MnAo/Ic42/barbie6.png';
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
  context2.drawImage(imageObj, 25, 85);
};
```

```css
#displaycake_sketch, #displaycake_sketch_2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="298" height="397" id="displaycake_sketch"></canvas>
<canvas width="298" height="397" id="displaycake_sketch_2"></canvas>
```

Comment: that's sweet thanks, may I ask what is the  context2.drawImage(imageObj, 25, 85); does?

Comment: @DownCrow its just for demonstration. don't worry about it. you can just use  `context.drawImage(imageObj, 25, 85)`

Answer (score 1):

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
```

This is the line that controls the coordinates; the first `10` is the `x` value and the second `10` is the `y` value.

Comment: P.S. -- I'd set the source before defining that onload function.

Comment: If you like an answer and it answers the question thoroughly, you should consider upvoting and accepting it (click the up arrow and the check to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can move the image using x,y coordinate with `.drawImage(image,x,y)` function

```
if(document.getElementById('fig1').checked){
      var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 20, 20);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fsFMyfNLNG8/TuZs45U0dZI/AAAAAAAAg38/QIjqug0MnAo/Ic42/barbie6.png';    
 }
```

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_images.asp